# Form submission (ajax) does not work with submit (only with click) but in the second option does not validate fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a clasic form submition with ajax but it only works with $("button").click(function()and so it does not validate fileds properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".response" ).hide();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".gumb").click(function(){
   event.preventDefault();

        var formData = $('#my_form').serialize();
         var pogoji = $("#pogoji").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'pogoji='+ pogoji + '&email=' + email;

        $.ajax({
            url:"action_page.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString, 
            success:function(result){

               $( ".response" ).show();
               $( "#obrazec" ).hide();
            $( ".prijavatext" ).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<html>
      <form name="Form" id="obrazec">

  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-poštni naslov" required />
            <br>
      <input id="pogoji" type="checkbox" name="pogoji" value="Pogoji" required /> <label style="">Strinjam se s pogoji</label>
        <br>
 <button class="gumb" form="obrazec" type="submit" onclick>Potrdi</button>


</form> 
</html>
```

I know it should work with submit: $("button").submit(function(); why it does not work?
Or if click is ok, how to make form validate fields?

Comment: a button doesn't have a submit event (please correct me here, if I'm wrong). It's the _form_ that fires that event, so hook it to `$("#obrazec").submit(...`

Comment: `<button class="gumb" form="obrazec" type="submit" onclick>Potrdi</button>` Remove that `onclick`

Comment: By the way, the data you're sending `'pogoji='+ pogoji + '&email=' + email;` looks like a `GET` method, not a `POST` one

Comment: true that the button does not have the `submit` event but as the OP is using Ajax it'll be tricky to implement as ajax will not return a value...the validation would need to occur client side which is sortof useless

Comment: @Jeff you can use a `button` since the event is based on `click`, not `submit`

Comment: what fields require validating and how are you doing that?

Comment: this is just snipets it is not my whole code

Comment: .gumb is ok no need to use button since i have a lot of buttons on website

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".response" ).hide();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#obrazec").submit(function(event){
        
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('submitted with html validation working');
        var formData = $('#my_form').serialize();
        var pogoji = $("#pogoji").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'pogoji='+ pogoji + '&email=' + email;

        /*$.ajax({
            url:"action_page.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString, 
            success:function(result){

                $( ".response" ).show();
                $( "#obrazec" ).hide();
                $( ".prijavatext" ).hide();
            }
        });*/
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<form name="Form" id="obrazec">

    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-poštni naslov" required />
    <br>
    <input id="pogoji" type="checkbox" name="pogoji" value="Pogoji" required /> <label style="">Strinjam se s pogoji</label>
    <br>
    <input class="gumb" form="obrazec" type="submit" value="Potrdi">

</form> 
</html>
```

Use Jquery submit method and pass the event in submit function to prevent the `form submit event`.

Comment: How then is he meant to handle the form data without a handler file?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb I was talking about the event which has to be passed in js function: `$("#obrazec").submit(function(event)`
and ofcourse action_page.php is required. I have commented the ajax code so that ajax does not fire while running code snippet